# Why my program does not print true result in C

Tags: c, loops

I've found a code about finding longest string in an array and print it with strrev(); function.
My code works successfully, but if my first string was larger than other strings my program does not understand.

This is my prototype:

```
void LongStr(char str[][50],int n);
```

and This is my Main() function:

```
int main()
{

    char str[size][wsize];
    int n;

    printf("\n How many words to accept:- ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\n Enter %d words:- \n \n",n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%s", str[i]);

    LongStr(str,n);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is my LongStr(); function:

```
void LongStr(char str[][50],int n)

{

    int Max = strlen(str[0]);
    int len;
    int c;

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
    len = strlen(str[i]);

        if( len > Max )
        {
        c = i;
        Max = len;
        }

    }
    printf("\n The longest string with reverse model is: \"%s\" \n \n",strrev(str[c]));
}
```

Example:

FirstString

SecondLongestString

ThirdString

output: strrev("SecondLongestString");

Example:

FirstString

SecondString

ThirdLongestString

output: strrev("SecondLongestString");

Example:

FirstLongestString

SecondString

ThirdString

output: crash!

Thanks.

Comment: What value would `c` have if the first string is longest?

Comment: In `LongStr()` you forgot to initialise `c` for the case when `str[0]` is longest. So do it like this: `int c = 0;`

Comment: I dunno this is not my code, for now I'll do this:
int c = 0;
Please wait a moment

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I did it ( c = 0 ), problem fixed! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If the longest string is the first `c` is never initialized, which makes it garbage and most likely a huge number to index the array.

You should initialize it to 0:

```
void LongStr(char str[][50],int n)
{

  int Max = strlen(str[0]);
  int len;
  int c = 0;
  // ...
}
```

PS: although this problem doesn't occur with `len`, I'd say it's probably good practise to initialize it to something too. In other words, initializing all variables is a good thing. However, I haven't code in `C` in a long time and I'm not sure if this is the norm.

Answer (score 1):

Really simple it's just a missing piece in your code

```
int Max = strlen(str[0]);
int len;
int c;
```

You need to give the `c` a value that why it's not working because it doesn't have a base value so try to change your code to

```
int Max = strlen(str[0]);
int len;
int c = 0; // base value of 0
```

Comment: Yes of course, its right, I did and problem fixed. Thank you dude.

Comment: Sorry didn't answer quickly for some reason it didn't want to post :D good luck